# MapInfo .mbx labeler tool

Tags: labeling, mapinfo

I've recently been upgraded to MapInfo 12.5 I'm trying to trace a MapInfo .MBX tool called labeler - I've used it in the past to transfer the geographic position of current MapInfo labels to a separate text layer. I've looked on the PBinsight community downloads page, and it doesn't seem to be there to download.  It also doesn't appear in the MapInfo Tools menu when I use MapInfo and it is not in the Program files directory on my pc. Any ideas where I can locate this file to load it into my pc?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a 32-bit version of MIPro, look in C:\Program Files (x86)\MapInfo\Professional\Tools